# Ruby script folder structure

Tags: ruby

I have several Ruby scripts that have been refactored to use common methods. What folder structure should I use for these files?

For example: I have reports "Grower", "Fecal", "30Day", "30DayFecal", etc. that all use methods in files `"date_of"`, `"get_fecal_data"`, `"get_fy"`, `"chart_fecal"`, etc.  I'm thinking that I should set up folders like;

```
App
    -Grower
    -Fecal
    -30Day
    -30DayFecal
    -lib
        -date_of.rb
        -get_fecal_data.rb
        -get_fy.rb
        -chart_fecal.rb
```

Please advise.

Comment: Dare I ask what you're building?

Comment: Maybe the question needs to be framed in terms of any utility that can be gained from particular folder structures

Comment: I am building apps that create charts and gather them into PDF files.  Each app makes use of other common methods and therefore I think these should be in a LIB folder, while each app should be in its own folder for clarity.  Having all the code in one folder just confuses things.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're being partially influenced by the Rails folder layout.

```
app
  models
  controllers
  views
lib
...
```

You can use that, since it is a common way to think, and will aid you getting advice from others.  Just be sure to make it clear that you're not developing a Rails app, so you don't create other confusions.

#### Views

These can be any output-formatters.  Rails app commonly export data in .csv format, for instance.

#### Controllers

These, along with *services* and related concepts, are things that manipulate data after a Model has retrieved it from a 'store' (e.g. a file on disk, database, or anything).

A common convention is that Controllers depend upon Models, whereas Lib[raries] is self-sufficient.  Some would say that Services depend upon external API data.

Comment: And it is true that I am influenced by that since I consider each app to be like a model and the methods they use to be in lib.  Is that wrong?

Comment: As per the reason this question was put on hold: nothing is "wrong".... you can make up any convention you want to.  You can literally make up any convention you like; it won't hinder the rub interpreter in its operation.  If you want to follow conventions introduced by rails, or something else, then perhaps re-write the question that way.